# Sort nested tuple in Ascending Order

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting, tuples

I have a nested tuple similar to:

```
cluster = [(0,0), (0,2), (0,1), (2,1), (1,2), (2,0), (1,0), (0,1)]
```

I am trying to sort the values in ascending order. Not by first element or second, but ascending order. **The result should be**:

```
sorted_cluster = [(0, 0), (0, 2), (0, 1), (1, 2), (1, 2), (0, 2), (0, 1), (0, 1)]
```

Looking online, solutions are usually to either sort by the first or second element, but in this case i wish to sort in ascending order. I was able to do:

```
for i in range(len(cluster)):
    sorted_cluster.append(sorted(cluster[i])
```

However, in doing so, i am returning a nested list inside a nested list which is not what i am looking for. As when i use `Counter` it recognizes an "unhashable list".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sorted` **always returns a list**, so just convert it into a tuple. And don't loop over the indices of cluster if you are just going to use the indices to access the elements inside a list, *iterate over the elements themselves* the Pythonic way:

```
for c in cluster:
    sorted_cluster.append(tuple(sorted(c)))
```

Comment: Thank you. Iterating over the elements saves substantial time.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work

```
cluster = [(0,0), (0,2), (0,1), (2,1), (1,2), (2,0), (1,0), (0,1)]
sorted_cluster = []
for i in range(len(cluster)):
    sorted_cluster.append(tuple(sorted(cluster[i])))
```

tuple will solve your problem as it will convert list into tuple which is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you. The solution was converting it into a tuple. I voted the other answer as it was quicker.